# How to format accentuated letters ( like french letters )?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I created a php file to echo a french text , and I use this text in an ajax file ( the responseText ) . My problem is that when using the ajax function from javascript then I must show the french responseText into an alert ; so there is the problem of accentuated letters such as "à" or "é". In HTML we use `&eacute;` to format "é". So how to format "é" and "à" in PHP so that I can use them in javascript and ajax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UTF-8 for php file encoding and type it in usual way.

Comment: The problem is that the meta code is also shown in the ajax response text. So how to dismiss the meta ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use htmlentities() on your PHP string.